# javascript iterate over array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

I'm working in an Angular app and inside a controller I need to iterate over an array of objects. This is the controller and the code involved in this situation:

```
myapp.controller('LoginController', ['$scope',  function(scope) {
    // Users for test
    this.users = [
        {
            name: 'admin',
            password: 'admin',
            role: 'ADMIN'
        },
        {
            name: 'employee',
            password: '12345',
            role: 'EMPLOYEE'
        }
    ];
    console.dir(this.users); // Prints an array of objects correctly

    // called when user submits
    scope.login = function() {
        console.log('login(). User: ');
        console.dir(scope.user); // Prints the object with user's input (also correct)

        var found = false;

        for(let u of this.users) {
            console.log('Comparing with:');
            console.dir(u);

            if(u.name == scope.user.name && u.password == scope.user.password) {
                console.log('Found!');
                found = true;

                // do something else...
            }
        }

        if(!found) { // show error message... }
    }
}]);
```

The problem is that when I submit the login form (call to `scope.login()`) I get an error message in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
    at m.scope.login (loginController.js:44)
    ...
```

`loginController.js:44` corresponds to `for(let u of this.users) {` line. I searched through the web (W3 Schools, MDN and this site also) but the solutions didn't worked for me. I already tried the following solutions:

- `for(var u of this.users)`
- `var u; for(u in this.users)`
- `for(var i = 0; i < this.users.lenght; i++)`: This changes the error message to `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I'm feeling that it's something simple but I cant't figure out what it is (I'm not very skilled in Javascript, sorry). Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Is `this.users` undefined?

Comment: Why are you using `this`? Should you not use `scope` or just a normal `var` or `let`? Because when you get to the function, `this` refers to the function

Comment: @Chifilly It's `controller as` syntax. It is preferred in favor of `$scope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope is changing within the login function, so the variable `this` isn't the same before as it is within that function.

Before `scope.login = function() {` you can write:

`var _this = this;`

then use `_this.users.forEach(function(user) {`

or `for (var i = 0; i < _this.users.length; i++)`

Comment: I'll take your answer as correct, I used `var users = [...]` so I can use it throughout the controller and worked perfectly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The `this` context changes inside your `scope.login = function () {}`, as it's an object method, `this` is a reference to `scope`. try this:

```
myapp.controller('LoginController', ['$scope',  function(scope) {
    var that = this; // reference to the correct this context
    // Users for test
    this.users = [
        {
            name: 'admin',
            password: 'admin',
            role: 'ADMIN'
        },
        {
            name: 'employee',
            password: '12345',
            role: 'EMPLOYEE'
        }
    ];
    console.dir(this.users); // Prints an array of objects correctly

    // called when user submits
    scope.login = function() {
        console.log('login(). User: ');
        console.dir(scope.user); // Prints the object with user's input (also correct)

        var found = false;
        for(let u of that.users) { // use the correct context here
            console.log('Comparing with:');
            console.dir(u);

            if(u.name == scope.user.name && u.password == scope.user.password) {
                console.log('Found!');
                found = true;

                // do something else...
            }
        }

        if(!found) { // show error message... }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: You could also just change `this.users` to `scope.users` and everything will work as expected.

Comment: It's worth noting that `that != $scope`, the difference won't be immediately noticeable in the controller, but will be on the HTML, also using `this` opposed to `$scope` is fairly opinion based, I believe a reason to use `this` would be to force dot notation when referencing it in the HTML with the `Controller as` syntax  (because not using dot notation *can and will* eventually give unexpected errors)

Comment: `this` inside a method on an object refers to the parent object. In this case `this` inside a method on the `$scope` object references `$scope`. You are correct that `this` is not ALWAYS `$scope`, but in this case it is.

Comment: It actually doesn't, as you can see [in this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes), angularjs's scopes aren't the javascript reference that would be retrieved with `this`, rather they're a collection handled by angularjs to encapsulate the data (where `this` is a child scope and `$scope` is a parent scope)... you can verify this by using the debugger in your browser to breakpoint on a `this` see what it evaluates to and then seeing what `$scope` evaluates to; you will find that `$scope.ctrl` is what `this` refers to in the top level of the controller

Comment: Note: when I say `$scope.ctrl` the `ctrl` refers to what the controller is named with then `Controller as ctrl` syntax, when that syntax isn't used `this` isn't found in `$scope` (and it's properties aren't found either)